# Using join() in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-2.7, process, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

My question pertains to the code below:

```
import multiprocessing
import math
import time


def do_work():

   for i in range(1,10,1):
      math.cos(i)


workers = [ multiprocessing.Process(target=do_work) for i in xrange(20) ]

for t in workers:
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

time.sleep(100) # put here to simply indicate main is busy doing something

for t in workers:
    print t.name + " joining"
    t.join()
```

As you can see my parent process is sleeping for a long time before joining on child processes. And my child processes run real quick.

**Question is:**

Is it ok for main process to wait for a long time before joining on child processes as in the example above? Is there a danger that the child process will become Zombie by the time main process gets around to joining it ? Is there a problem with this code ? Is this bad code in some way ? How can I improve it ?

**My attempt:**

I tried to study the behavior. It seemed ok to me. But I guess once I did see a child process turn into a zombie, atleast `ps` output showed that.

Comment: Why is the main process waiting?  Are you doing some actual work in the main process, or is it really sleeping?  If the latter, the `join()` method will do the sleeping for you, and probably be more efficient about it.

Comment: calling `t.join()` in the main thread for an "already finished" `t` has no harm. However, general principle is to join after starting the child thread in order to have the main thread wait for the child to finish executing its task.

Comment: @Kevin I added a comment. Just consider that main has to do some work before joining on child processes.

Answer (score 0):

A process becomes a zombie if its parent dies without acknowledging its exit status. This might happen, for example, if you forcefully terminate your script with a KILL signal.

If your parent process is busy doing something else and cannot call `join()` immediately after a child exits is totally fine.

The issue is when you keep creating processes without joining the old ones. In such cases you'll soon run out of resources in your OS.

In your specific example there's no harm at all as the children processes are set as daemon and you're joining them at a certain point. Keep in mind that `join()` blocks until the given process expires so you don't need to sleep to wait for it.

Comment: You mean : "Keep in mind that join() blocks until the given process **expires** so you don't need to sleep to wait for it."

Comment: My sleep in main thread(parent process) is to simply indicate some busy work by the process, nothing else.